# Token expiration forgot password Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

We have a cluster on which we have keycloak. I noticed a vulnerability: When users attempt to reset their passwords, accessing the reset password link concurrently on multiple devices allows for the possibility of changing the password using the same link multiple times.

Steps to reproduce:

```
1. Request a password reset link from the application.

2. Copy the link from the received email and paste it in the browser of your choice, on 2 different devices.

3. Try updating the password on any of the instance and click on “Submit”.

4. Now, choose a different password and update it on the second instance.

5. Now you can login using the last password you set.
```

Is there wait to set that once the password is updated, it should not allow a second password update even if it opened in another tab?

The only thing I found is the parameter: "Override User-Initiated Action Lifespan", in the Tokens page, but I can only set the expiration time in minutes, not in the number of updates.